# Build error with MFMailComposeViewController in a libGDX / RoboVM project

Tags: java, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to add functionality to an existing iOS libGDX app (using RoboVM) so that when a scene2d.ui button is pressed, an MFMailComposeViewController popup is displayed with a predefined set of CSV files attached that are stored in the app's Library > local folder. Here's the code I have so far:

Imports & members:

```
import org.robovm.apple.foundation.*;
import org.robovm.apple.messageui.MFMailComposeResult;
import org.robovm.apple.messageui.MFMailComposeViewController;
import org.robovm.apple.messageui.MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate;
import org.robovm.apple.uikit.*;
import org.robovm.objc.ObjCObject;

private UIWindow mailWindow;
private UIViewController mailViewController;
private MFMailComposeViewController mailPicker;
```

Methods:

```
private void createMailWindow() 
{
    mailWindow = new UIWindow(UIScreen.getMainScreen().getBounds());
    mailViewController = new UIViewController();
    mailWindow.setRootViewController(mailViewController);
}

private void sendEmail(String fileName, String subject, String body) 
{
    mailPicker = new MFMailComposeViewController();
    mailPicker.addStrongRef(mailWindow);
    String path = NSBundle.getMainBundle().getResourcePath();

    if (fileName != null)
    {
        path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/Library/local/" + fileName;
    }

        MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate delegate = new MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate()
        {
            public void mailComposeControllerDidFinish(MFMailComposeViewController controller, MFMailComposeResult result, NSError error) 
            {
                controller.dismissViewController(true, null);
                mailPicker.removeFromParentViewController();
                mailPicker.removeStrongRef(mailWindow);
                mailWindow.setHidden(true);
                mailPicker = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void didFinish(MFMailComposeViewController controller, MFMailComposeResult result, NSError error) 
            {

            }
        };

        mailPicker.setMailComposeDelegate(delegate);
        mailPicker.addStrongRef((ObjCObject) delegate);

        if (fileName != null)
        {
                // attach CSVs here...
        }

        mailPicker.setSubject((subject != null ? subject : "Test Results"));
        mailPicker.setMessageBody((body != null ? body : "Please find attached the latest results data."), false);

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
        {
            mailWindow.getRootViewController().presentViewController(mailPicker, true, null);
            mailWindow.makeKeyAndVisible();
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code in place and Eclipse doesn't flag any problems until I attempt a build, whereby I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/robovm/rt/bro/NativeObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.mmu.cfa.DesktopMain.main(DesktopMain.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.robovm.rt.bro.NativeObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 49 more
```

I've added the RoboVM Cocoa Touch Library and the RoboVM Runtime Library to my main project's build path. If I remove these two methods, my project builds without error. Is there something else I need to setup to get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

In a Libgdx application, the **main project is shared** by the projects of all supported platforms.

So **main project must contain platform independent code**.

*RoboVM Cocoa Touch Library* and *RoboVM Runtime Library* are platform dependent and would work only on iOS and not on desktop, android, html etc.

---

### Solution

1. Remove *RoboVM Cocoa Touch Library* and *RoboVM Runtime Library* dependencies from main project.
2. Add those dependencies to the RoboVM project. (If they are not already present.)
3. **Create an interface** representing the functionality that you require **in the main project**.

   ```
   public interface EmailHandler {
       public void createMailWindow();
       public void sendEmail(String fileName, String subject, String body);
   }
   ```
4. **Create an implementation class in the robovm project** with the code you have already written.

   ```
   public class RobovmEmailHandler implements EmailHandler {

       @Override
       public void createMailWindow() {
           // Your code goes here.
       }

       @Override
       public void sendEmail(String fileName, String subject, String body) {
           // Your code goes here.
       }
   }
   ```
5. Add the `EmailHandler` **parameter to the constructor** of `ApplicationListener` (your **main game class** in main project).

   ```
   public class MyAwesomeGame extends Game {

       private EmailHandler emailHandler; // Use it wherever you like.

       public MyAwesomeGame(EmailHandler emailHandler) {
           this.emailHandler = emailHandler;
           // Rest of constructor.
       }
   }
   ```
6. **Supply** the implementation **argument** in `RobovmLauncher` (main class of robovm project).

   ```
   public class RobovmLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate {

       @Override
       protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
           EmailHandler emailHandler = new RobovmEmailHandler();
           IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
           return new IOSApplication(new MyAwesomeGame(emailHandler), config);
       }
   }
   ```

---

**Note:**
Projects of other platforms would start shouting at you to provide an `EmailHandler` to them. This is natural and expected. You should provide platform specific implementation of the interface for each platform you want to target.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.